# How do I force the game to use DirectX 9?

Tags: a-game-of-dwarves

My computer has "issues" running games with DirectX 10 (It can run then, however when I try to run a game with Directx 10 or 11, strange laggy "tearing" occurs for some strange reason). Is there any way (such as -dx 9 or otherwise) that I can force A Game of Dwarves to run using Directx 9?

These two images show one of the two issues caused:

[image]

[image]

And this image shows a bit of the laggy tearing (Not the best picture, the issue is a lot bigger than just that, however it is localised to just the lower toolbar area)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to make it work with DirectX9, as outlined by the devs:

http://steamcommunity.com/app/200370/discussions/0/864949719243209566/

http://steamcommunity.com/app/200370/discussions/0/864949719200570278/

The engine used by the developers does not support DirectX9 at all.

For your screen tearing, there is an option in the game called "VSync". If you enable that and restart the game, the tearing will be gone. However, make sure that VSync is not forced off in your graphics card panel (Catalyst or NVIDIA Control Panel).

Here is how you find it if you own an ATI Graphics Card:

[image]

Comment: Vysync is already enabled, and even if its not, it has no effect what soever. I think the issue could be related to HP's classic rubbish-as-heck switchable graphics